# How to embed a dynamic generated HTML document into HTML document?

Tags: html, testing

I am writing a testing framework for my web app. The case is to test some AJAX methods. While there are some server side errors, the response of AJAX calling is a HTML document log. However, I would like to display the HTML document in the same testing page while the response received. I am afraid I cannot insert the HTML document into a div since it is not html snippet but a complete HTML document. Is there anyway to deal with the problem without server-side effort?

Besides, I have considered about iframe. However, it seems that it only could display a webpage by specifying the url.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I tested Aaron's second solution. It surprised me that I could insert a complete HTML document into HTML document and keeps its styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create an `iframe` and load the HTML document into it
2. Or locate the `body` element in the result and just add the content of that element to the `div` next to your test case.

The first one can cause problems with Cross Site Scripting (which you may or may not apply to your case). The second one means you have to merge the styles of the results into your test HTML document or it won't look as you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Can you explain in detail how to put the html document in the iframe. Since the HTML document is created on the fly, it does not have an corresponding url, how do I put it in the iframe. I've tried iframeElt.innerHTML = responseHTML in Chrome. But it didn't work.

Comment: You can find the document with `iframeElt.contentWindow.document`. I'm trying to find an example how to replace the whole content but that seems a bit hard. Try to strip the `html` tags around the string and write that into the document :-/